# Relative Layout dynamic textView

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

```
 RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl);
        for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            final TextView textViewUtente = new TextView(mContext);
            final TextView textViewMessaggio = new TextView(mContext);
            final TextView textViewData = new TextView(mContext);
            textViewUtente.setText(sepUser[i]);
            textViewMessaggio.setText(sepMessage[i]);
            textViewData.setText(sepDate[i]);
            int curTextViewIdUtente = 1000+i;
            int curTextViewIdMessaggio = 2000+i;
            int curTextViewIdData = 3000+i;
            textViewUtente.setId(curTextViewIdUtente);
            textViewMessaggio.setId(curTextViewIdMessaggio);
            textViewData.setId(curTextViewIdData);
            final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);



            params.topMargin= 100+i*150;

            textViewUtente.setLayoutParams(params);
            layout.addView(textViewUtente, params);

            params.topMargin= 250+i*150;

            textViewMessaggio.setLayoutParams(params);
            layout.addView(textViewMessaggio, params);

            params.topMargin= 100+i*150;
            params.rightMargin=200;
            textViewData.setLayoutParams(params);
            layout.addView(textViewData, params);
        }
```

I need to create 3 textview (that create the post on the blog from the user) every for loop like this:

Post 1:

TextViewUSer         TextViewDate

TextViewMessage

Post 2:

TextViewUSer         TextViewDate

TextViewMessage

I'm able to make one blog's post(a group of text view) above the other.
I just can position them, like this, from eachother. they stuck one above the other.

I also trued with addRules the .ABOVE and others but it's even worst cause they stuck all on the top left corner

Comment: Use `ListView` for this purpose.

Comment: What would it change in this position part?

Comment: `ListView` is used for displaying contents of repeated nature. You don't have to create an array of `TextView`. You can use `BaseAdapter` and create a [Custom ListView](https://github.com/krrishnaaaa/CustomListViewDemo) for the posts.

Comment: I honestly never tryed it.
And i'll be able to place each group of view in the way i want, filled with the stuff i need inside a for loop?

Comment: I included a GitHub url for the demo I created in previous comment. Try that... Its good to use the components build for specific purpose.

Comment: WHy when i import a project and run it, it let me run it just on emulator and not my real device? it happens only when i import a project

Comment: You can transfer the generated apk into your device to run it on your device.

Comment: BTW thnk u! i imported parts of your code and its fully workin :) ill use this method from now on

Answer (score 1):

You can **add Rules** to your textviews like this

```
 tv1 = new TextView(this);
 tv1.setId((int)System.currentTimeMillis());

 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);                
 lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, recent.getId());

 tv1.setText("Time: "+System.currentTimeMillis());
 rr.addView(tv1, lp);
```

Egs.

```
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv1.getId());
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, someOtherView.getId())
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT)
```

Comment: I edited and added that i triyed with addRules ABOVE and RIGHT_OF but it stuck all on top left corner, everry post, im not even able to make a post under the other like before